# flutter `tester.scrollUntilVisible` throws "Bad state: Too many elements" exception

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, exception, flutter-listview

I have the following elements encapsulated into a single `ListView` in my material app:

```
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Flutter Layout")),
            body: ListView(children: [
              fibonacciSection,
              // a ListView supports app body scrolling when the app is run on a small device.
              Image.asset("images/lake.jpg",
                  width: 600,
                  height: 240,
                  fit: BoxFit
                      .cover), // BoxFit.cover tells the framework that the image should be as small as possible but cover its entire render box.
              titleSection,
              buttonsSection,
              textSection,
              statesSection
            ])));
```

And when I run the unit tests which contain the following code snippet:

```
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp(key: Key("StateManagemetTests")));
    final listFinder = find.byType(Scrollable);
    final itemFinder = find.byType(TapboxB);
    // Scroll until the item to be found appears.
    await tester.scrollUntilVisible(
      itemFinder,
      500.0,
      scrollable: listFinder,
    );
```

It throws the following exception:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown running a test:
Bad state: Too many elements

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Iterable.single (dart:core/iterable.dart:656:24)
#1      WidgetController.widget (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:69:30)
#2      WidgetController.scrollUntilVisible.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:1190:15)
#3      WidgetController.scrollUntilVisible.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:1188:39)
#6      TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#7      WidgetController.scrollUntilVisible (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:1188:27)
#8      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///usr/src/flutter/flutter_app_layout/test/widget_test.dart:50:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 3 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `scrollUntilVisible()` with `dragUntilVisible()` solves the problem!
I don't find anything at all for `scrollUntilVisible()`. Is that an outdated API which should be removed from the framework?

Comment: Both `dragUntilVisible` and `scrollUntilVisible` do exist. Here is the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/scrollUntilVisible.html

Answer (score 5):

The error seems to occur when there are more than one `Scrollable` in the widget tree. Then Flutter doesn't know which one to scroll. You can solve that by first finding the correct `Scrollable` and telling `scrollUntilVisible` to use it:

```
   // Scroll Save button into view
   final listFinder = find.byType(Scrollable).last; // take last because the tab bar up top is also a Scrollable
   expect(listFinder, findsOneWidget);
   await tester.scrollUntilVisible(acceptButtonFinder, 100, scrollable: listFinder);
```

Enjoy!